# Query Database Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to JavaScript and never used Ajax before. I want to add an OnClick to the Index.cshtml, so when a row is clicked, my code will query database (MSSQL)and return results.
I have two tables in database, User and Contact. The primary key in User, UID， is the foreign key in Contact. Here's my code:

Controller

```
  private UserInfoEntities db = new UserInfoEntities();

  public ActionResult Index(){
      var users = from u in db.User orderby u.UID select u;
      return View(users.ToList());
}
```

View

```
@<Info.Model.User>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function showEmail() {
        var tb = document.getElementById("users");
        var rows = tb.rows;
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].onclick = (function() { 
               //some code that query Contact table using UID
               // and return Contact.Email in a popup windows or something
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<table class="table" id="users" onclick="showEmail()">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UID)
        </th>
    </tr>    
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UID)
        </td>   
    </tr>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `@<List<Info.Model.User>>`

Comment: Rather than set this function `onclick="showEmail()"` on table click, set it on row click like this - `<tr onclick="showEmail()">...`. Now you no need to iterate thru each row.

Comment: " for (var i = 1;" -- are you skipping the first row on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showEmail() {

               //some code that query Contact table using UID
               // and return Contact.Email in a popup windows or something

    }
</script>
<table class="table" id="users" >
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().UID)
        </th>
    </tr>    
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr onclick="showEmail()">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UID)
        </td>   
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: When a row is clicked, user.UID of that row is passed ot javascrip code as a parameter, and the code will query Contact table in database on where (user.UID == contact.UID), and return contact.EMAIL

Comment: not getting you. are you asking about how to pass parameter in it?